# What is the difference between this two notations?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

So, basically I want to know what is the difference (if there is any) between these two notations:

First example:

```
struct Node{
int data;
Node* next;
};
Node* head;
```

Second example:

```
struct Node{
int data;
struct Node* next;
}
struct Node* head;
```

I just want to know what's the difference between these two notations, and which is better two use?

Comment: In C++, there is no difference. The two examples do the exact same thing, the extra `struct` keyword on the variables is optional. Use the first way, it is shorter to type. But, in C, there is a difference, though.

Comment: Okay thank you. Which notation would you prefer or recommend to use?

Comment: First one is illegal in `C`.

Comment: I understand, thank you! :)

Comment: @MarekR true, but the question is tagged C++, and the first way is legal and preferred in C+=

Comment: @RemyLebeau just clearing up since you didn't specified difference in `C`. Basically choice which version use depends if it will be used with `C` only code or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know what is the difference (if there is any) between these two notations

`Node` is a type name of a class. It can be used only if the class has been declared. Example:

```
Node* ptr; // won't work without prior declaration
struct Node;

struct Node;
Node* ptr; // works because of prior declaration
```

`struct Node` is the same type name using elaborated type specifier. It is declaration of the class by itself. Example:

```
struct Node* ptr; // works without prior declaration
```

Elaborated type specifier can be used to disambiguate when a function and a class have the same name:

```
struct Node;

void Node();

void foo() {
    Node* ptr;        // this won't work
    struct Node* ptr; // this works
    Node();           // this is a function call
}
```

Given that in your example the class has already been declared, and there is no ambiguous function, there is no difference other than `struct Node` is about 64% longer to type.

> which is better two use?

Which ever you prefer. Do you like to type more or to type less?

---

Note about C language: In C, structs do not get a type name automatically, so they can only be referred to using an elaborated type specifier unless the struct has explicitly been given a type name using `typedef`. This is why you may see elaborated type specifiers used more commonly in C than in C++, as well as typedefs that would be redundant in C++.